# How can I link movie clip to URL via Flash Actionscript 2.0?

Tags: flash, button, actionscript, mouse, movieclip

I am trying to turn a movie clip into a button once the graphic catches your mouse as shown here:

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx/followease.htm

So, when the circle catches up to your mouse you have the option to click on that circle and go to a specified URL.  Is this possible, if so how?

==============================

These notes are from the various responses thus far.  I am still getting errors and cannot get the clip to function properly.  Here is the exact code that I am applying to the movie clip (mc):

```
onClipEvent (load) {
_x = 0;
_y = 0;
speed = 5;
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
endX = _root._xmouse;
endY = _root._ymouse;
_x += (endX-_x)/speed;
_y += (endY-_y)/speed;

import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// assuming the movie clip is called mc
mc.onRelease = function() {
getURL("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Any further suggestions are much appreciated and thanks for those who have contributed thus far.

Comment: please update your question to state that you want this solved in AS2

Comment: got it updated and I will keep this in mind for any future questions, thanks.

Comment: your code at the moment is mixing as2 and as3 and is generally just weird. See the new solution offered by chris, that one is working as long as you are pasting it on the movieclip

Answer (score 2):

1. `onClipEvent(enterframe)` has unmatched `}`
2. those import statements are for AS3
3. if you're going to put the script directly on a movieclip (that is, select it with mouse and press F9 to bring up the script panel, and paste the code on it), you don't have to use its name (mc)

---

try pasting this on the movie clip~

```
onClipEvent(load) {
    _x = 0;
    _y = 0;
    speed = 5;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame) {
    endX = _root._xmouse;
    endY = _root._ymouse;
    _x += (endX-_x)/speed;
    _y += (endY-_y)/speed;
}

onClipEvent(mouseUp) {
    getUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: @DanielMesSer yea~ I actually tested it, but seems like the OP has left~

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add a click handler to your movie clip and use [flash.net.navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) to go to a specified URL.

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// assuming the movie clip is called mc
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
var url: String = "http://www.google.com"
function onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried this out, but got a variety of errors including `The class or interface 'MouseEvent' could not be loaded.`  Would I just past this code after the code that is displayed in the link?  Also, I am using Flash 8, so it does not have Actionscript 3.0 available, would that cause errors?

Comment: I've added the missing import for MouseEvent, but I've forget most of as2 to help at the moment...

Comment: please update your question to clearly state that you want this solved in AS2

Comment: I have updated the question with this info and more details on the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the solution provided by @Chris but in an AS2-context

in the code sample, mc is a link to the circle movie clip that is following the mouse

```
mc.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, please have a look at my question update because I imagine that I am making a simple mistake here.